# How do i know whether android application explicitly killed by user or not?

Tags: android

I have an application which uses some resources internally.

Problem : if user explicitly removes application from recent apps list, it kills the entire application but i must close resources when application is killed explicitly.

Is there any callback method is calling when application is closed by the user ?

Comment: Please explain, **completely and precisely**, what "resources" you think that you need to "close" when the user is terminating your process?

Answer (score 1):

What's the difference if the user kill your app/ the system kill your app or just the user move to another app and put your app in background.

In any case you shouldn't leave open resources when you app isn't active.
Just close all resources on `onStop` of your activity

Comment: Actually i am developing app for mobile call communication, when i called to someone, once call is accepted by other user and then now i am clicking on home button after that i am closing application totally but still other guy who accepted my call is still connected even though my app is killed .

Comment: when the app is killed explicitly by the user i would like hang up the   call but i dont know which method will be called when app is killed.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with those kind of apps, but you might wanna look on [android services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: just i need to know , Is there any method which is going to be called android OS when app is killed by user explicitly.

Comment: then how can we know whether app is closed or not in my application code.

Comment: like I sait- user `onStop`/ `onDestroy` or use service

Comment: please explain clearly what would be the internal mechanism when application is killed explicitly. I mean is it going to destroy all activities if it is the case will on destroy method is called each and every Activity class ????